# Mac control center "now playing" info not showing duration over 1h

Tags: macos, cocoa, mpnowplayinginfocenter

For a Mac app I'm trying to use the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` with playback controls and track info.

I'm using the `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration` property to set the track duration, with the number of seconds as NSNumber wrapped value.

Tracks over 1 hour do not show the full duration and roll over at 59:59.

Is there any way to make items in the control center show their full duration & elapsed time?

[image: Invalid time]

Notes:

- The image shows Control center information for a track with a duration of 1:52:33 and current play position is 1:00:05.
- The seek bar works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a macOS bug since media played using QuickTime Player also exhibits the same erroneous behavior. Please file a macOS feedback report!

Comment: I sent a "Feedback" report.